# Copy cms page and create many for different stores

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

Requirements: I have to display same CMS page for different site so I have to create copies of 1 cms pages to display for other store-views. Is there any method to copy 1 cms page like we can do copy product to create duplicate products?

Comment: Magento has a 'Store View' setting you can select any number of stores on for each CMS page and static block. I'm not sure why this is an issue, unless you have to translate each one as well?.

Comment: Thishat is not a issue. I have to create 22 language stores that means each cms and static page will have 22 copies. Thats why i am looking for solution if thats available in magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use one CMS page for different store views in Magento. Instead you should have different CMS pages for each store view.

And unfortunately it's not possible to duplicate CMS pages in Magento. But there are bunch of extensions which can do the job for you. Below are some of those extensions.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/duplicate-cms-page-1.html
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-cms-page-blocks.html

Hope this helps.